# How to fetch only 5 records from a table using join on the same table

Tags: sql, oracle11g

The following query takes nearly 1 minute to execute. The table has 200k records. Can it be rewritten to perform faster?

```
SELECT  CLIENT_FNM  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT  TRIM(A.CLIENT_FNM)  AS client_fnm 
FROM gen_clientvendor_m A JOIN gen_clientvendor_m B ON (TRIM(A.CLIENT_FNM) = TRIM(B.CLIENT_FNM))
WHERE A.CLIENT_VENDOR_ID <> B.CLIENT_VENDOR_ID
AND A.PARTY_TYPE  = 'C'
AND A.status   = 'A'
ORDER BY TRIM(CLIENT_FNM))
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
```

Comment: Its taking alomost 1 min of time. Pls help

Comment: I woulld imagine it's fine as is, but it would help if you didn't have to trim your `client_fnm` values at the join, and if you had an index on that field.

Comment: why are you using a subquery here? just use the regular query and take top 5 order by client_fnm

Comment: Also joining on a trim is hurting you - consider trimming everything first and then running the query

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT  a.CLIENT_FNM   
FROM (select distinct TRIM(CLIENT_FNM)CLIENT_FNM, CLIENT_VENDOR_ID, PARTY_TYPE, status from gen_clientvendor_m) A 
JOIN gen_clientvendor_m B ON  A.CLIENT_FNM  = TRIM(B.CLIENT_FNM)
WHERE A.CLIENT_VENDOR_ID <> B.CLIENT_VENDOR_ID
AND A.PARTY_TYPE  = 'C'
AND A.status   = 'A'
ORDER BY TRIM(CLIENT_FNM))
WHERE ROWNUM <= 5
```

Comment: Hi Daniel it is not working, I am using Oracle DB and sql developer.

Comment: ok updated syntax - mine was for sql server - hows the updated code?

Comment: try using fetch first 5 rows only

Comment: whats the error- also are you using Oracle 12c R1 (12.1) or above?

Answer (score 0):

I'd aggregate over `TRIM(client_fnm)`, so as to read the table only once.

```
select client_fnm
from
(
  select
    trim(client_fnm) as client_fnm,
    row_number() over (order by trim(client_fnm)) as rn
  from gen_clientvendor_m
  group by trim(client_fnm)
  having count(distinct client_vendor_id) > 1
  and count(case when party_type = 'C' and status = 'A' then 1 end) > 0
)
where rn <= 5;
```

I've replaced Oracle's `ROWNUM` with starndard SQL's `ROW_NUMBER`. (Better would be `FETCH FIRST n ROWS ONLY`, but that's only available as of Oracle 12c.)

To get this fast you should have the following function index:

```
create index idx1 on gen_clientvendor_m(trim(client_fnm));
```

or even a covering index:

```
create index idx2 on gen_clientvendor_m(trim(client_fnm), party_type, status, client_vendor_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

For your query I'd provide the following two indexes:

```
create index index1 on gen_clientvendor_m(party_type, status, trim(client_fnm), client_vendor_id);
```

to find the records with `PARTY_TYPE = 'C' AND status = 'A'` quickly and provide `trim(client_fnm)` and `client_vendor_id` for the join.

And

```
create index index2 on gen_clientvendor_m(trim(client_fnm), client_vendor_id);
```

to quickly self-join on these two fields.